# Как вывести содержимое ссылки (ссылка на 3д модель)?

Tags: javascript

На данный момент всё выглядит вот так jsfiddle.net/x6uqtLab/6/ , но при срабатывании определенных radiobutton нужно выводить не соответствующую нажатым jpg картинку(как у меня в коде), а 3D модель. Ссылка на одну из них  https://sketchfab.com/models/176738e6a3cf4bf486bce3abe284c0d4/embed  Я не силён в JavaScript, поэтому прошу Вашей помощи.

HTML-----------

```
<div id="rows" class="rows">
 <div class="row">
     <img src="" width="80">
     <label><input type="radio" name="1" class="radio"></label>
     <img src="" width="80">
     <label><input type="radio" name="1" class="radio"></label>
     <img src="" width="80">
     <label><input type="radio" name="1" class="radio"></label>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
     <img src="" width="80">
     <label><input type="radio" name="2" class="radio"></label>
     <img src="" width="80">
     <label><input type="radio" name="2" class="radio"></label>
     <img src="" width="80">
     <label><input type="radio" name="2" class="radio"></label>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
     <img src="" width="80">
     <label><input type="radio" name="3" class="radio"></label>
     <img src="" width="80">
     <label><input type="radio" name="3" class="radio"></label>
     <img src="" width="80">
     <label><input type="radio" name="3" class="radio"></label>
 </div>
```

JS----------------------------

```
var imageToggle = (function(doc){

var box = doc.querySelector('#rows'),
    rows = box.querySelectorAll('.row'),
    rowCount = rows.length,
    toggleAll = [],
    cartes = [],
    data = {},

    /**
     * @type Function
     * @return {[]}
     */
    getCheckeds = function()
    {
        var checkeds = toggleAll.filter(function(toggle){
            return toggle.checked;
        });

        return checkeds.map(function(toggle, i){
            return  toggle.value;
        });
    },

    /**
     * @type Function
     * @param {[]} arr
     * @return {[]}
     */
    cartesianProduct = function (arr)
    {
        return arr.reduce(function(a,b){
            return a.map(function(x){
                return b.map(function(y){
                    return x.concat(y);
                })
            }).reduce(function(a,b){ return a.concat(b) },[])
        }, [[]])
    };

[].forEach.call(rows, function(row, i){

    var toggles = row.querySelectorAll('[type="radio"]');
    cartes[i] = [];

    [].forEach.call(toggles, function(toggle, j){
        cartes[i][j] = toggle.value = j;
        toggleAll.push(toggle);
    });

});

cartes = cartesianProduct(cartes);

return function(images, callBack)
{
    callBack = callBack || function(){};

    if(images.length != cartes.length) {
        throw new Error('Должно быть ' + cartes.length + ' изображений');
    }

    images.forEach(function(image, i){
        data[cartes[i].join('-')] = image;
    });

    toggleAll.forEach(function(toggle){
        toggle.addEventListener('change', function(){
            var checkeds = getCheckeds();
            if(checkeds.length == rowCount) {
                callBack(data[checkeds.join('-')]);
            }
        });
    });
};
})(document);
var result = document.querySelector('#result'),
len = Math.pow(3, 3),
images = [],
i = 0;

for(; i < len; i++) {
images.push('image-' + (i + 1) + '.jpeg');
}

imageToggle(images, function(imageUrl){
result.innerText = imageUrl;
});
```

Comment: В вопросе ссылка битая.

Comment: Т. е. вам нужно, что бы при клике на radiobutton рядом с кнопкой открывалась 3D модель?

Comment: Суть такова, есть 3 группы в каждой по 3 радиобатона. В зависимости от радиобатонов выбранных в каждой группе, должна выводиться определенная 3д модель. Проще говоря, под радио баттонами находятся материалы, из которых сделан стул : 1 группа из 3х радиобатонов. 3 варианта спинки. 2 группа из 3х радиобатонов - 3 варианта ножки стула.  3 группа из 3х радиобатонов - 3 варианта сидения. Вот мне нужно чтобы в зависимости от выбранной конфигурации выводилось определенное, заранее занесенное в базу изображение в виде 3Д модели

Comment: Можно я предложу свой вариант реализации? Просто сложновато разбираться в чужом коде

Comment: Можно, а то я в тупике. Примерно должно выполняться как здесь http://sitdown.sk/detail/raya_23/129/category/135/type/3   там немножко ниже варианты с выбором компонентов стула

Comment: @shadiq, смотри, что вышло

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так. Вот на стороннем редакторе: https://jsfiddle.net/zp56szoe/3/

```js
$(function() {
  // Начало самого кода
  var categories = {human: '0x0', technics: '1x0'}; // Список категорий. Установить надо начальные значения
  var view = function(c) {
    // Список всех возможных комбинаций
   var models = {
     human_0x0_technics_1x0: "b4d09f17df1043b2b8baeae51347a4b2",
      human_0x1_technics_1x0: "eb320ba995e040789c1192bcf860af5e",
      human_0x2_technics_1x0: "24b736f75b29464f8b2a62eb6d421533",
      human_0x3_technics_1x0: "057893ec02134e4b86c495ff505fd004",
      human_0x0_technics_1x1: "9432459670914c4eb007fbe525966b6d",
      human_0x1_technics_1x1: "aefc4f2a29914e779e97be7cf5e7675b",
      human_0x2_technics_1x1: "7355bbb7edf14fed9273eedadf513f5c",
      human_0x3_technics_1x1: "7a8eb56b3eeb49f793b5a1dfbb7cac35",
      human_0x0_technics_1x2: "b6fee17b9cd14255ace12ff2a8205754",
      human_0x1_technics_1x2: "bb4a3847ec8d4c908736a29805560799",
      human_0x2_technics_1x2: "2d6212aec95243809eed0971fb96dd7b",
      human_0x3_technics_1x2: "8199bfdac59b44e9a7a0daae8436750e",
      human_0x0_technics_1x3: "692a107c048f41079f22455a3c28dc1b",
      human_0x1_technics_1x3: "c07b2847faf7459190163a8b999b4b4e",
      human_0x2_technics_1x3: "9b56b004a8494ad69e754dd780108a3c",
      human_0x3_technics_1x3: "4d8ddf708a714e6898c7147b3ca3e0c5"
    };
    // Создание "ключа"
    var key = '';
    for(var i in c){
      if(key == ''){
       key += i+'_'+c[i];
      }else{
       key += '_'+i+'_'+c[i];
      };
  };
    $('#model_view').attr('src', 'https://sketchfab.com/models/'+models[key]+'/embed'); // Загрузка нужной модели
  };
  view(categories); // Отправляем начальную модель
  $('.rows .row input[type="radio"]').click(function() { // Клик на radiobutton
    var e = this;
    categories[$(e).attr('name')] = $(e).attr('value'); // Запись данных в список
    view(categories); // Отправление модели
  });
});
```

```css
body {margin: 0; font-family: arial}
.view {width:100%;height:300px;border: 0;background-color:black}
.rows {margin: 10px 10px 0 10px}
.rows .row {margin-bottom: 10px}
.rows .row .title {font-size: 18pt;margin-bottom: 5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<iframe src="" class="view" id="model_view"></iframe>
<div class="rows">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="title">Категория 1</div>
      <label><input type="radio" name="human" value="0x0" checked=""><span>0</span></label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="human" value="0x1"><span>1</span></label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="human" value="0x2"><span>2</span></label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="human" value="0x3"><span>3</span></label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="title">Категория 2</div>
      <label><input type="radio" name="technics" value="1x0" checked=""><span>0</span></label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="technics" value="1x1"><span>1</span></label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="technics" value="1x2"><span>2</span></label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="technics" value="1x3"><span>3</span></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: У меня есть такой еще пример, чтобы понятней было как должно выглядеть и работать https://jsfiddle.net/LLe2zL2h/ . Т.е. только при выборе всех 3х радиобатонов выводить модель стула, который соответствует выбранным компонентам. Картинки в коде кривые, но суть я думаю понятна будет )

Comment: @shadiq, к сожалению нужно указывать все возможные комбинации категорий, что бы отобразить нужную модель

Comment: у меня код рабочий, тот что я скинул. Но он выводит jpg а нужно ссылки эти, я просто не знаю как их записать в массив и выводить в дальнейшем.

Comment: @shadiq, ладно, прости, но я не помогу :(

Comment: а ты не знаешь как  создать массив с этими ссылками ? единственное что мне нужно изменить в коде, это записать куда-то эти значения, а потом их выводить. Но я не знаю как это сделать :(

Comment: @shadiq, можно их закидывать в обычный массив `arr[]` и выводить по id. А ещё можно записать по ключу: `arr['ключ 0'] = 'значение'` и выводить так: `arr['ключ 0']`. А записывать в массив, я бы сделал, при клике на один из radio

Comment: а ты можешь написать как будет выглядеть создание самого масива состоящего из ссылок https://sketchfab.com/models/176738e6a3cf4bf486bce3abe284c0d4/embed     ?

Comment: @shadiq, прости, но не покажу. Поищи в интернете, там должно быть что-то похожее

Comment: Разобрался с этими моделями, если интересно https://jsfiddle.net/x6uqtLab/13/